# Opening Cities Revealed data from 1990s?

Tags: file-formats, aerial-photography

I have been given a lot of aerial imagery from the mid-1990s that is in '.crv' format. The software/company at the time was called 'Cities Revealed'.

Does anybody know how I'd go about opening it?

I have: QGIS, ArcGIS, AutoCAD and FME at my disposal.

Comment: If you could make one or two available I might have a go reverse-engineering it. Do you know any metadata about each file (location,r resolution etc)?

Comment: Thanks for the offer but I'm not allowed by my company to export it. I will try and find some metadata

Comment: Metadata on its own is probably no use. It is helpful when presented with an unknown binary format. If you've done any google research (which you surely have) on the company name etc could you edit the question and include it so we know where you have already trod?

Comment: Are these the same people?  [The GeoInformation Group, publishers of Cities Revealed aerial photography](https://www.geospatialworld.net/news/cities-revealed-3d-buildings-available-for-google-earth/)

Comment: The data I have is for the UK so it makes sense that they're the same people. I didn't find that in my web-trawl. I will contact them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should contact [The GeoInformation Group, publishers of Cities Revealed aerial photography](https://www.geospatialworld.net/news/cities-revealed-3d-buildings-available-for-google-earth/) to see if they can provide any insight about their `*.crv` format.